# Pandas flipping sign on certain rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      underlyingSymbol           symbol                  description  averagePrice  marketValue putCall  shortQuantity  longQuantity
    0             COST  COST_071720P285   COST Jul 17 2020 285.0 Put         1.947        0.080     PUT            0.0           1.0
    1             COST  COST_071720P290   COST Jul 17 2020 290.0 Put         2.493       -0.115     PUT            1.0           0.0
    2             COST  COST_071720C330  COST Jul 17 2020 330.0 Call         2.383       -2.370    CALL            1.0           0.0
    3             COST  COST_071720C335  COST Jul 17 2020 335.0 Call         1.587        1.200    CALL            0.0           1.0
    4              GLD   GLD_071720P151    GLD Jul 17 2020 151.0 Put         0.887        0.015     PUT            0.0           1.0
    5              GLD   GLD_071720P154    GLD Jul 17 2020 154.0 Put         1.413       -0.020     PUT            1.0           0.0
    6              GLD   GLD_071720C169   GLD Jul 17 2020 169.0 Call         1.583       -1.655    CALL            1.0           0.0
    7              GLD   GLD_071720C172   GLD Jul 17 2020 172.0 Call         1.137        0.450    CALL            0.0           1.0
```

I've been trying to flip the signs on the `averagePrice` column but only if `shortQuantity` is greater than `longQuantity`

This is supposed to be the end result:

```
  underlyingSymbol           symbol                  description  averagePrice  marketValue putCall  shortQuantity  longQuantity
0             COST  COST_071720P285   COST Jul 17 2020 285.0 Put         1.947        0.080     PUT            0.0           1.0
1             COST  COST_071720P290   COST Jul 17 2020 290.0 Put         -2.493       -0.115     PUT            1.0           0.0
2             COST  COST_071720C330  COST Jul 17 2020 330.0 Call         -2.383       -2.370    CALL            1.0           0.0
3             COST  COST_071720C335  COST Jul 17 2020 335.0 Call         1.587        1.200    CALL            0.0           1.0
4              GLD   GLD_071720P151    GLD Jul 17 2020 151.0 Put         0.887        0.015     PUT            0.0           1.0
5              GLD   GLD_071720P154    GLD Jul 17 2020 154.0 Put         -1.413       -0.020     PUT            1.0           0.0
6              GLD   GLD_071720C169   GLD Jul 17 2020 169.0 Call         -1.583       -1.655    CALL            1.0           0.0
7              GLD   GLD_071720C172   GLD Jul 17 2020 172.0 Call         1.137        0.450    CALL            0.0           1.0
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should give you what you want.

```
df.loc[df['shortQuantity'] < df['longQuantity'],'averagePrice'] = df['averagePrice'] * -1
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the desired results also

```
df.loc[df['shortQuantity'] < df['longQuantity'],'averagePrice'] = -df['averagePrice']
```